# Consequences of using Virtual keyword on all methods in a class?

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I am new to TDD and I am using `Moq` as my mocking framework.
I am trying to check if a method has been called in my class. 
The class is not implementing any Interface.

```
 var mockFooSaverService = new Mock<FooSaverService>();
 mockFooSaverService.Verify(service => service.Save(mockNewFoo.Object));
```

to make this work I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391483/what-is-the-difference-between-an-abstract-function-and-a-virtual-function/391492#391492) that I have to make the `Save()` method as a `Virtual` method.

**Question:**

What are the consequences of using `Virtual` keyword for all methods in a class just for the sake of making it testable?

Comment: "The class is not implementing any Interface." Have you thought about changing that, to express your dependencies more clearly?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry I don't understand what do you mean exactly? Shall I provide more details of my dependencies hierarchy?

Comment: The other (and better) approach is to do use an Interface. Making all methods virtual seems a little wobbly.

Comment: You've said your class doesn't implement an interface. You haven't said *why* it doesn't implement an interface. Presumably that means at the moment, the code using the service is tightly coupled to that specific service class. Introduce an interface to reduce coupling, and mock (or fake) that interface instead.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know it is a strange to make all the method Virtual just for make your class testable and not using Interface. but is there any proper reason for not making methods Virtual? I am not talking about using Interface instead. I am asking about the effects of Virtual keyword just for the sake of testability?

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right. I know I have to introduce an interface to make it more loosely coupled. But Imagine I have a WebApi controller which I want to verify if one of its specific method has been called. Shall I introduce an interface and implement my WebApi Controller from that interface again?

Comment: Well what would be calling your WebApi controller directly? That's normally just part of WebApi routing, isn't it? You really need to be clearer about your question - if it's just "what are the consequences of making a method virtual" then that isn't really specific to testing. It's not clear whether you're trying to make your code testable, or learn more about C#. Separate those two concerns - you can always ask two different questions for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

As per the comments, the need for the virtual keyword indicates that your class hierarchy is too tightly coupled, and you should apply [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) to decouple them from eachother. This has the "happy" side effect of making your class hierarchy easier to Unit Test, as dependencies can be mocked via the interface abstraction.

**In more Detail**

The need make all public methods virtual to allow Moq to override them is frequently indicative of a separation of concerns or class coupling smell.
e.g. [this scenario needed virtual methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607520/moq-only-one-method-in-a-class) because class under test has multiple concerns, and there was a need to mock one method and actually invoke another method in the same system under test.

As per @JonSkeet's comment, it is commonplace SOLID best practice to abstract dependencies as interfaces. As it stands, your class under test (May I call it "Controller"?) is dependent on the concrete `FooSaverService` to save Foos.

By applying the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), this coupling can be loosened, by abstracting just the externally useful methods, properties and events of `FooSaverService` to an interface (`IFooSaverService`), and then

- `FooSaverService` implements `IFooSaverService`
- `Controller` depends only on `IFooSaverService`

(Obviously, there are likely other optimizations, e.g. to make the `IFooSaverService` generic, e.g. `ISaverService<Foo>` but not in scope here)

Re : `Mock<Foo>` - it is fairly uncommon to need to Mock simple data storage classes (POCO's, Entities, DTO's etc) - since these will typically retain data stored in them and can be reasoned over directly in unit tests.

To answer your question re implications of `Virtual` (which is hopefully less relevant now):

- You are breaking the (polymorphic) [Open and Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) - it is inviting others to override behaviour without deliberately designing for this - there may be unintended consequence.
- As per Henk's comment, there will be a small performance impact in administering the [virtual method table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413483/virtual-method-tables)

**A code example**

If you put all this together, you'll wind up with a class hierarchy like so:

```
// Foo is assumed to be an entity / POCO
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
}

// Decouple the Saver Service dependency via an interface
public interface IFooSaverService
{
    void Save(Foo aFoo);
}

// Implementation
public class FooSaverService : IFooSaverService
{
    public void Save(Foo aFoo)
    {
        // Persist this via ORM, Web Service, or ADO etc etc.
    }
    // Other non public methods here are implementation detail and not relevant to consumers
}

// Class consuming the FooSaverService
public class FooController
{
    private readonly IFooSaverService _fooSaverService;

    // You'll typically use dependency injection here to provide the dependency
    public FooController(IFooSaverService fooSaverService)
    {
        _fooSaverService = fooSaverService;
    }

    public void PersistTheFoo(Foo fooToBeSaved)
    {
        if (fooToBeSaved == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fooToBeSaved");
        if (fooToBeSaved.ExpiryDate.Year > 2015)
        {
            _fooSaverService.Save(fooToBeSaved);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you'll be able to test your class which has the `IFooSaverService` dependency as follows:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FooControllerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void PersistingNullFooMustThrow()
    {
        var systemUnderTest = new FooController(new Mock<IFooSaverService>().Object);
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => systemUnderTest.PersistTheFoo(null));
    }

    [Test]
    public void EnsureOldFoosAreNotSaved()
    {
        var mockFooSaver = new Mock<IFooSaverService>();
        var systemUnderTest = new FooController(mockFooSaver.Object);
        systemUnderTest.PersistTheFoo(new Foo{Name = "Old Foo", ExpiryDate = new DateTime(1999,1,1)});
        mockFooSaver.Verify(m => m.Save(It.IsAny<Foo>()), Times.Never);
    }

    [Test]
    public void EnsureNewFoosAreSaved()
    {
        var mockFooSaver = new Mock<IFooSaverService>();
        var systemUnderTest = new FooController(mockFooSaver.Object);
        systemUnderTest.PersistTheFoo(new Foo { Name = "New Foo", ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2038, 1, 1) });
        mockFooSaver.Verify(m => m.Save(It.IsAny<Foo>()), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR;
Another good answer is - making classes extendable, and providing virtual methods (i.e. the possibility to extend them) is "feature" of that class. And this feature needs to be supported and tested as any other feature.

Much better explanation can be read on [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/22/61803.aspx).